# What to use in 'SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "???", in Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to write code to send a simple mail from asp.net page.
Confusion is over what to write under "smtp server", when I want to send mail using Microsoft Outlook 2007.

Two sets of code I'm trying:-
1.)

```
MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage();
objMail.From = "angenlina.jolie@compnayabc.com";
objMail.To = "brad.pitt@companyabc.com";
objMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
objMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
objMail.Subject = "Hi Sweetheart";

string smtpadd = "USA-LA-MAIL1.corp.hollwood.com";

SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtpadd";
SmtpMail.Send(objMail);
```

2.)

```
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.Host = "USA-LA-MAIL1.corp.hollwood.com";
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");   
                MailMessage email_msg = new MailMessage();
                email_msg.To.Add("brad.pitt@companyabc.com");
                email_msg.From = new MailAddress("angenlina.jolie@companyabc.com");
                email_msg.Subject = "test mail...";
                email_msg.Body = "Hi SweetHeart";
                email_msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                smtp.Send(email_msg);
```

Now my problem is what server name should I use for Microsoft outlook 2007(MS exchange server)?

Comment: Are you saying that you have Outlook 2007 installed on the web server and configured with an Exchange mailbox?

Comment: @ Andrew: to put it simple, I wanna use Microsoft Outlook 2007, installed in PC(linked with my company mail server) to send mail.

Comment: SOL unless that copy of Outlook is configured in the ASP .NET service account.

Comment: copy of Outlook is configured in the ASP .NET service account---------> HOW TO DO IT?

Comment: Either "runas" Outlook in the service account or use MAPI instead of SMTP. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my problem is what server name should I use for Micrsoft outlook 2007(MS exchange server)?

Are you sending email via MAPI (using their "Outlook profile") or via SMTP through an Exchange Server? They're not the same.

If you are sending through Exchange then the server will need to be configured to relay mail via SMTP. In which case, put the Exchange server in as the SMTP server.

If you're sending email via MAPI then you'll be using whatever mail server is configured in their "Outlook profile". Which could be SMTP, IMAP, Webmail (with a Hotmail connector or Gmail connector) or Exchange Server.

EDIT:

It sounds like you want to use the Exchange server via MAPI. [Here](http://g8.cx/mapi/) is a good primer to the technologies involved.

Bear in mind that if you're configuring MAPI profiles from within the ASP .NET application you're going to pay attention to the service account the ASP .NET application runs as and that the MAPI is sometimes interactive and not suitable for service based applications.

You may be better off having an administrator configure the Exchange server to route email via SMTP (which is most likely is, unless you have a spam appliance in front of the server which handles SMTP).

Comment: when I checked inside MS outlook:- 'TOOLS-->OPTIONS-->MAIlSETUP-->EMAIL ACCOUNT'. Under that the 'type' of mail, company mail required to be used in the code, is 'EXCHANGE'. So I want to use it.

Comment: Todda.. i am checking into, what u hav suggested. So for the current scenario, i guess ur's reply is the answer. Thnx 4 help

Answer (score 2):

try something generic i.e
Email Client setup information

```
IMAP server: imap.smtpserver.in
POP server: pop.smtpserver.in
SMTP server: smtp.smtpserver.in
```

Webmail
To access your email through a web browser visit http://webmail.smtpserver.in
smtpserver.in is your smtpserver host address.